# NiFi - Update Luwak (Lucene) Indexes in Processor

Tags: java, lucene, apache-nifi

I am trying to create a custom processor using the [Luwak](https://github.com/flaxsearch/luwak) Lucene indexer, so I can run queries on incoming flow files. What I am trying to figure out is the best way to update the query indexes that exist inside of the Luwak monitor (example code below).

**EDIT - More Usage Context**

By update, I mean allowing an outside user to add / update / remove queries that are being run against the incoming flowfiles. We would be starting with a fixed set of queries,  but then would want to allow a user or users the ability to change the queries being executed against the incoming messages. Here in lies the challenge, changing the queries that are being executed.

Any other options I should consider? It appears to take about ~20s to update the queries, if there are 10k of them. This would most likely be rare, but re-load / startup time is something I am trying to consider.

**Options I have considered:**

1. Use an UpdateAttribute and update on every flowfile. Not ideal, especially if there are a bunch of queries to index.
2. Use http, AWS SQS, etc. to send a high-priority flow file to update (make higher than any other source). Not terrible, but still doesn't seem right.
3. Use the NiFi API to start / stop the processor on update.  Doesn't seem like a very efficient way to perform the updates, especially if they happen quite frequently.

**Instantiate Monitor:**

```
Monitor monitor = new Monitor(new LuceneQueryParser("field"), new TermFilteredPresearcher());
```

**Add Queries - What I am trying to optimize:**

```
        //Add queries to the monitor
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : bucketList.entrySet()) {
            MonitorQuery q = new MonitorQuery(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
            monitor.update(q);
        }
```

Comment: (IMHO) the problem is not clear. how following options correlates: `UpdateAttribute`, `AWS SQS`, and `NiFi API to start / stop` ?

Comment: Shouldn't the queries be loaded when the processor starts and then be fixed? The thing that is changing is the incoming flow file which will be matched against the indexed queries.

Comment: @daggett Bryan Bende: I added an EDIT above which provides more context. We would want to allow users to change the queries that are being applied at runtime, which is where I am having the challenge. They would not stay fixed indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your processor starts you could start a background timer thread that periodically builds a new monitor and then replaces the one being used by the processor.

You would probably want to make a member variable in your processor like:

```
AtomicReference<Monitor> monitorHolder = new AtomicReference<Monitor>();
```

Then in @OnScheduled you can build the initial monitor and set it in the holder.

Then in onTrigger you always first get the Monitor:

```
Monitor localMonitor = monitorHolder.get();
```

Then in the background thread you can call monitorHolder.set(newMonitor) which won't affect the current execution of the processor, but will take effect the next time onTrigger is called.

Comment: Ahhh. Great Idea Bryan! Thanks. I will try that.